# How can I make Post, Put , Delete requests from fake api with RestSharp? I am getting Json Deserialize error

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public double discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
}

public class RootViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
}

public ProductClient()
{
    _url = "https://dummyjson.com/products/";
     var options = new RestClientOptions(_url);
     _client = new RestClient(options);
}

public async Task Delete(int id)
{
    var request = new RestRequest()
         .AddQueryParameter<int>("Id", id);
          // https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?id=12
          await _client.DeleteAsync(request);
}

ProductController
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> Deleted(int id)
{
     var response = await _client.Delete(id);
     return Ok(response);
}
```

Fake API JSON URL : https://dummyjson.com/products

I tried everything since yesterday, but I couldn't. I'm trying to pull post put and delete operations from fake API to my own API, but I can't.

There is an example that I tried to delete above, but I couldn't manage to write a method for the current post and put.

Comment: I delete my answer due to the question is unclear. *When I return from my ProductViewmodel and list it on the view screen, will the data I deleted appear? I need post and put methods too, I can't do it *. If you read the API docs, it mentioned that the data will not delete from the server. When you try to delete the data, the data will be returned with some properties indicate it is deleted (soft-delete).

Comment: But anyway you should pass the Id as the portion of URL ("https://dummyjson.com/products/1"), but not with query params.

Comment: What I mean is, if I delete that data when I enter the id, will the data I deleted appear as deleted when I want to list the fake data?

Comment: Technically the fake data will still show the deleted record. The Delete API returns the sample data with deleted info (soft-delete), it will not hard-delete the record in the server.   Unless you need to store these deleted records in your side (database), then map with the fake data to filter which is not deleted. Achievable but need time to implement. And for me, it is unnecessary as this API is just for demonstration.

Comment: It's unclear where you get the deserialisation error, as RestSharp won't deserialise anything when you call `Delete`.